# Comparing Date objects correctly

Tags: javascript, date

I am using a jQuery UI datepicker to show a range of dates that are available to the user.  I get the date ranges from an API in the form of

```
"DateRanges": [
  {
    "StartDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

The problem is that I am running a comparison on the dates in the `beforeShowDay` API mapping function, but when I try to convert these dates into a JavaScript Date object for comparison, the Date() constructor is converting the dates to local time and therefore causing the date to change.

For example, if I use `new Date("2014-08-22");` then I would expect a Date object that was set to 8/22/2014 at 12:00 AM but instead it is showing 8/21/2014 at 5:00 PM PST.  Therefore my comparison does not work correctly because of the conversion.

What can I do to force the Date() object to not change to local time when making comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the parsing logic defaults to the UTC time zone when you do not supply one. To get the expected time, pass a time zone.

```
new Date("2014-08-22T00:00:00-0700");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

This is another tidbit from the docs that might help (depending on how you are generating those dates):

> Given a date string of "March 7, 2014", parse assumes a local time zone, but given an ISO format such as  "2014-03-07" it will assume a time zone of UTC. Therefore Date objects produced using those strings will represent different moments in time unless the system is set with a local time zone of UTC. This means that two date strings that appear equivalent may result in two different values depending on the format of the string that is being converted (this behavior is changed in ECMAScript ed 6 so that both will be treated as local).

so you could also use:

```
new Date("September 11, 2014");
```

and you will get a date in your local tz (for me the output is: "Thu Sep 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)").